# I downloaded the Ubuntu desktop torrent (Alternative), now what?

Tags: utorrent

I selected Alternative and then Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS desktop version. I planned on downloading the server version ( I thought I needed the both of them), but I stopped it after learning that only one of them was needed. Okay, the torrent download is completed, I opened the file, all I see  is a desktop image file ( and the server file for some reason as well), also the torrent file for the server. What do I do now?

Apologies, I'm new to this changing OS thing...

Answer (score 0):

You could use the guidelines provided by ubuntu themselves on how to get this done using a USB or CD/DVD.

For USB : https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/FromUSBStickQuick

Generally I would look up what I want to do exactly on youtube and follow instructions because you can see how and what they do on those videos rather than following written instructions.